# Rails JSON request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a issue where I cant get my rails v4 app to recognize a JSON request. I am sending the following header('Content-Type' => 'application/json') from my mobile/client app and the request payload is a JSON string.

```
Started POST "/devices" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-25 17:50:46 -0800
Processing by DevicesController#create as */*

respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.json do
    # Request does not come in this block
  end
end
```

However when I append ".json" to my request URL, my rails app is able to process it as a JSON request

```
Started POST "/devices.json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-25 17:13:43 -0800
Processing by DevicesController#create as JSON
```

Anything I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the `Content-Type` header describes request's type, not respose's.

> Rails determines the desired response format from the HTTP Accept
>   header submitted by the client.

What you can do is check for `request.content_type` and `render json: {}` or HTML accordingly.